# Is it possible in HDFS to partially encrypt a table? (some columns only)

Tags: hadoop, encryption, hdfs, cloudera

I cannot find any attinent source. 
I am working in Cloudera CDH 5.3
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: could you be a little more specific, hive or hbase?

Comment: I have not decided whether hbase or not, architecture is in the making, that is why the question is so generic. therefore is it or not possible to have columnar encryption somewhere in cloudera? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In case the tables are in **Hive**, Then cloudera has sentry ,refer [this](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cloudera-manager/v4-latest/Cloudera-Manager-Managing-Clusters/cmmc_sentry_config.html).

Sentry as of now doesnt support column level security , it could restrict users/groups from accessing/reading the content of the particular table.

Now in the case of **Hbase** tables. The hdfs file could be restricted be changing the access privilege or owner privileges.This could also be done for hive tables.

**==Update==**

Currently column level data encryption is not supported , there are few posts in [jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-6329) regarding the same.

As a workaround i would suggest the following :

1. Develop a UDF for encryption and decryption separately using some
   algorithm.
2. Use the encrypt function while data insertion, this would encrypt
   the data and store it as encrypted in the hdfs.
3. Use the decryption UDF for decrypting whenever data is read.

Hope this helps.

Comment: for what i understood sentry is for role based access. I am asking for encryption, i don't want to restrict my user group.

Comment: I +1 your answer because of the time you take to answer it, but I am not sure I understand your workaround, since encrypting a file is not the same as encrypting part of it

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at Apache Accumulo it has got cell level security, and I believe that it is an installable service in Cloudera Manager

http://accumulo.apache.org/1.4/user_manual/Security.html

Each individual datam can be security labeled.